# Typescript/nodejs: variable implicitly has type 'any' in some locations

Tags: node.js, arrays, typescript, variables

I'm using typescript with nodejs to init DB data, I want to declare a global array variable to use inside functions :

```
export { };
import {Address,CodePostal} from 'api/models';
const faker = require('faker')
const _ = require('lodash')
const quantity = 20
var codes

async function setup() {
  const adminUser1 = new User(ADMIN_USER_1);
  await adminUser1.save();

  await seedCodesPostal()
}

async function checkNewDB() {
  const adminUser1 = await User.findOne({ email: ADMIN_USER_1.email });
  if (!adminUser1) {
    console.log('- New DB detected ===> Initializing Dev Data...');
    await setup();
  } else {
    console.log('- Skip InitData');
  }
}

const seedCodesPostal = async () => {
  try {
    var codesPostal = []
    for (let i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
      codesPostal.push(
        new CodePostal({
          codePostal: faker.address.zipCode("####")
        })
      )
    }
    codesPostal.forEach(async code => {
      await code.save()
    })
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  codes = codesPostal ***// here is the error : variable codes has implicitly type 'any' in some locations where its type cannot be determined ***//
}

const seedAddresses = async (codes: any) => {
  try {
    const addresses = []
    for (let i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
        addresses.push(
          new Address({
            street: faker.address.streetName(),
            city: faker.address.city(),
            number: faker.random.number(),
            codePostal: _.sample(codes),
            country: faker.address.country(),
            longitude: faker.address.longitude(),
            latitude: faker.address.latitude(),
          })
        )
    }

  } catch (error) {

  }
}

checkNewDB();
```

I want to put the content of codesPostal in the function seedCodesPostal inside codes variable and the pass it as params in the function seedAddresses.

how to define the codes variable as array of CodesPostal correclty ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When you create an array like `let arr = []` the type is inferred to be `any[]`, because Typescript doesn't know what will be in that array.

So you just need to type that array as an array of `CodePostal` instances:

```
var codesPostal: CodePostal[] = []
```

You also need to assign `codes` within the `try` block, or else `codesPostal` could never be set if the `catch` is triggered.

With those edits you end up with the simplified code here:

```
const quantity = 20

// Added type here
var codes: CodePostal[] = []

class CodePostal {
  async save() { }
}

const seedCodesPostal = async () => {
    try {
        // Added type here.
        var codesPostal: CodePostal[] = []

        for (let i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
            codesPostal.push(
                new CodePostal()
            )
        }
        codesPostal.forEach(async code => {
            await code.save()
        })

        // Moved assignment inside try block
        codes = codesPostal

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=32&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAjgVwIZigSygTxgXhgJgAYAoYgejJgEEATGgUxpiwAd6YALegJ3uIDck3GKAYQAXDADCIBgAUQ0JABsA2gF1cMDaWDKkECNNn0FS5TADexGDAOYwwGBCT96ACgCUVmAF9i-sSgkLAQ9IwyYmZQKlr2jjBeuAB8Vja2zNzY1hm5MBTUdIzMmGycPPQAdOl5MILCovQQ0SqSkaaKMWqaeDq5NXkAZiDC7sr0sGhahADcMFMAPPDIqBiYc2gA1JveObV5jc2dKpUsCBAc7gP7eWD0AO7G8sfKXtf7nu+2-jeHLcqVYbcACiSGAl3iTkaKTSN1ySHuSAwIhMlRcbjeN18ny++UoAFkQG4mAYIGgAOZgAC29FQ80gaAYmWwACNlCBgABrXGHLR-F4DAa+ERIKDgxI8bi7HngCAgcaVdnk9ySzwzIUBUhAA)

Comment: "Typescript doesn't know what will be in that array."
What? why not? And how does what you did address that?

Comment: @ahnbizcad The line `let arr = []` is what has no information about the type of array members. We fix that by declaring the type of the array as `CodePostal` via `let arr: CostPostal[] = []`.

Comment: oh the members, not the array itself. so that sets the first member as an array? doesn't that just run into a recursive problem? this is not self evident and needs a lot more explanation imo.

Comment: Recursive? No, there's nothing recursive here. And it's not the first member, it's all members. This is simpler than you think. `let arr: MyType[] = []` says "create an empty array where all members (to be added later) must be of type `MyType`". Here the `: MyType[]` is what types the array and its members, and `= []` assigns an empty array as the value. I don't know how to explain that more detail.

Comment: yes, there is. because you specified the first element of the array as array. if it didn't recognize the first array because the type of elements within it wasn't specified, then the same thing applies for when you specify the first element of the array as array. obviously.

Comment: @ahnbizcad  _"you specified the first element of the array as array"_ This is not correct. The only arrays in this answer have a type of `CodePostal[]`. Which means each element of the array must an instance of `CodePostal`. No part of the code in this answer declares the _first_ element of the array. Only the types of the array members that are allowed, at any position. Which part do think types only the first element as an array? I'm happy to explain exactly what each element in that part does if you'd like.